# Where does homotopy appear in the proof for Cauchy's integral theorem using Green's theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'll quickly summarize the proof:

Let $f$ be an analytic function over $\mathrm{Int(\gamma)}$. Let the derivatives of $f$ be continuous. Let $f=u+i v$, $dz=dx+idy$. Therefore:

$$\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\oint_{\gamma}(udx-vdy)+i\oint_{\gamma}(vdx+udy)=\iint_{\mathrm{Int(\gamma)}}\left( -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)dxdy + i\iint_{\mathrm{Int(\gamma)}}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right)dxdy=0$$

Where the last integral is true because $f$, since its analytic, must satisfy the  Cauchy-Riemann equations; and the second integral is true because of Green's theorem.

This is all well and good, but I don't understand where homotopy comes into play. Also, I don't really see why the derivatives must be continuous, instead of simply existing for all points in the region delimited by $\gamma$.

Comment: Green's theorem is really true because of homology, not homotopy.

Comment: Green's theorem, as a special case for general Stoke's theorem, doesn't use any kind of homotopy nor homology, it just need the fundamental theorem of calculus. Homotopy is required for a different thing: to see when two path integrals will have the same result

Comment: @Masacroso But when does that appear within the proof? I just can't see it.

Comment: @agaminon I dont see what proof are you seeing but you can take any book of differential geometry and search for Stoke's theorem and read it proof

Comment: Can you name your source book/site, or at least quote the line/part that is making you ask about homotopy in particular? That would help people (perhaps me later) give an answer that would help you the most.

Comment: Voting to close as that helpful context is still missing

Answer (score 1):

The usual Green's theorem involves a bounded open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\overline{\Omega}$ is, say, $C^1$ with corners. Then if $f, g$ are real valued (or complex valued) functions that are $C^1$ on a neighborhood of $\overline{\Omega}$, then
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}(f\,dx + g\,dy) = \int_{\Omega}(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})\,dx\,dy.$$
I'm sure that some of the above hypotheses can be relaxed, such as regularity of $\overline{\Omega}$ and regularity of $f, g$ near $\partial \Omega$.

The reason the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ should be continuous is so that $\int_{\Omega}(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})\,dx\,dy$ makes sense. Without continuity, we can't even be sure that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is integrable, whereas if $f, g$ are $C^1$, then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is bounded on the compact set $\overline{\Omega}$, hence integrable on the bounded set $\Omega$. Also, we need some kind of regularity on the derivatives because the fundamental theorem of calculus is used to prove Green's theorem.

Homotopy is not involved in Green's theorem. It is involved in theorems similar to Green's theorem, e.g. that homotopic closed curves have the same integral.

Comment: Homotopy isn't involved in Green's theorem but it is involved in Cauchy's theorem for integrals, Green's theorem here is just used to prove it. But I can't see where the homotopy requirement appears in this proof.

Comment: The version of Cauchy's theorem based on Green's theorem does not require homotopy. The theorem just says that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $C^1$ on a neighborhood of $\overline{\Omega}$, then $\int_{\partial \Omega}f\,dz = 0$. There is a version of Cauchy's theorem that uses homotopy. It says that if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are closed curves in $\Omega$ and are homotopic as closed curves and $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then $\int_{\gamma_1}f\,dz = \int_{\gamma_2}f\,dz$. This homotopy version can actually also be proved with Green's theorem.